# Connect Excel with SEC EDGAR

Tags: xml, excel, xbrl, vba

For a year and a half now i am faced with a frustrating problem in Excel; i started learning VBA and XML but it didn't do any good at all! I just didn't find any books with a relevant topic and Microsoft's help is pretty unhelpful! In a last-ditch effort, i taped it on a video searching for anyone who could help to maximize the potential of getting a bulls-eye answer and finally move forward constructing an economic model. My [video shows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExKVG1gtTFA&feature=youtu.be) analytically how i am stuck!!!

Please any help will be gold, i have a basic understanding of VBA and XML(read some books). I simply cannot give any more man-hours and i need your help!!!

Thank you, Marinos

PS: My video has a 16 sec intro. Couldn't resist it!+Any other way to automatically parse an XBRL document fast and efficiently and plug it's data into the mapped cells of a worksheet will be tons of help...!

Comment: All very interesting! Which is your question?

Comment: The XBRL taxonomy extension schema documents are different for different companies. Look at your video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ExKVG1gtTFA#t=305) The schema for ANN INC is size 36006 whereas the schema for TESLA MOTORS INC is size 47804

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we do it at my company:

1. Get an XML database to query your files. I recommend [BaseX](http://basex.org/) (it's the easiest to install)
2. Write the Queries to get the data you need. You will need to learn XPath and XQuery. If you already know XML you should know about XPath and there is a simple XQuery tutorial at [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/xquery/)
3. Call the queries from Excel. BaseX and most XML Databases are also web servers. You can call a query using an URL (like `http://localhost:8080/basex.....` ). You create a Table on Excel with that URL as source, or you can call it from VBA using the XMLHttpRequest object.

Hope you find this info useful.